# Responsive layout: middle content of centered div with fixed width must become the right column without overflowing

Tags: css, responsive-design, tablelayout

I have a centered div with a width of 700px, with a *middle* part that must become a right column when viewport is > to some width. I used absolute positioning for that purpose but like this column must be responsive, I don't know its width.

First, I would like to know what is the rule for how behave the width of absolute positioned elements which are out of their relative parent. Absolute positioning should use the width of their relative parent but when the element is out of that parent, the element is shrinked. If there is a word without space, it extends the element accordingly and everything follows. I don't understand how it works and how predict that behavior. It's the same when that element without width is supposed to start overflowing out of its parent.

Then, is there a way to make this column fills the right until it reaches the limit of the window without overflowing (with a little margin-right)? If I fix a big width on that column assuming it will be the max-width that column will achieve in the biggest viewport and use the overflow property to hide what is out of the window, of course, the absolute positioned element is just cut.
I really don't know how to make that responsive because it seems like absolute positioning removes the element from the flow, it is not made for my purpose. Of course, no JS, please. And it must support Internet Explorer since IE8.
The only solution that comes to my mind is to duplicate the content and use display:none/block to switch blocks with media queries but it means redundant code. I tried with a complicated display:table layout until I found that colspan doesn't exist.
(Just so you know, I have a left column too to take into consideration, the reason why I am using a three columns display:table layout. If that's relevant.)

Here is a simplified code:
I didn't put media queries but the aside-on-small-screen is obviously what it should look like on small screens, replacing the aside selector.

```css
main{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.colMain{
  background-color:green;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
}
.aside{
  background-color:red;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:320px;
}
.aside-on-small-screen{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="colMain">
    <div>stuff</div>
    <div class="aside">aside that must extend all the way to the right until it reaches the window limit</div>
    <div>stuff</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Thank you.

Comment: In RWD (Responsive Web Design), the majority of the lengths are measured in relative units like percentages, `em`s, `vw`s, etc. If you want `.aside` stretch you definitely going to need to assign a relative measurement.

Comment: Yeah, I know but responsiveness is more about how a layout is supposed to adapt to every screen than the fluid grid rule. Even with a fluid grid, I don't think it will resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems in one:

## First problem.

How to transform a middle content

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>stuff</div>
    <div class="aside">Middle content</div>
    <div>stuff</div>
</div>
```

in a right column that expends to the right without overflowing out of the window, when the rest of the past column "wrapper" must be a centered column of fixed width.

```
<div class="colLeft"></div>
<div class="wrapper" style="text-align:center; width:700px;">
    <div>stuff</div>
    <div>stuff</div>
</div>
<div class="aside">Middle content now to the right</div>
```

Absolute positioning doesn't help because without fixed sizes (% or px), it is out of the flow and the content of variable width won't adapt to the situation (and overflow).

*This can be easily solved with display table.*

## Second problem.

Display table/table-cell leads to the second problem.
To make three "columns" with display:table-cell, order is really important. That means the "aside" div must be the last element of its column (the wrapper column in my first snippet) in order to make it an independent cell of a row put to the right. If you don't have to worry about this story of middle content and you just have to switch a content at the end of a div to the right or a content at the beginning to the left, it's already over.
You just have to style colLeft, wrapper and aside of my second snippet with display:table-cell and use another global wrapper with display:table and some other styles like table-layout:fixed and width:100% to do the trick. With a media queries for small screen, you just have to hide the colLeft with display:none.

But if you need that middle content to be a middle content nonetheless on small screens and a right column on large screens, it's a different case.

*This can be solved with [anonymous table objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) and table-header/footer/row-group.*

With table-header/footer/row-group, you can reorganize your rows so you can put the "aside" at the end to transform it in an independent cell on large screens and place it in the middle with table-row-group on small screens:

```css
.header{
  background-color:green;
  display:table-header-group;
}
.footer{
  background-color:green;
  display:table-footer-group;
}
.aside{
  background-color:red;
  display:table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">stuff</div>
<div class="footer">stuff</div>
<div class="aside">Middle content</div>
```

## Third problem.

The hardest problem is the centered "column" of fixed width. With table-xxx-group, it is forbidden to put a wrapper around the table-header-group and table-footer-group to set a width of 700px because table-group are row elements and the wrapper will automatically becoming a table object, excluding the "aside" that won't be able to insert itself in the middle with its table-row-group style on small screens.
Without putting a wrapper around the "stuff", you won't be able to control the width of the created anonymous cell on large screens because you can't style something anonymous. So it takes a width of 1/3 like each cell.

```css
main{
  display:table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.colLeft{
  background-color:yellow;
  display:table-cell;
}
.header,.footer{
  background-color:green;
  /*no display style > it will create an anonymous cell
  object around the header/footer elements*/
}
.aside{
  background-color:red;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="colLeft"></div>
  <div class="header">stuff</div>
  <div class="footer">stuff</div>
  <div class="aside">Middle content now to the right</div>
</main>
```

*The solution is to use table-column-group/table-column. You will be able to style your columns and set a width to the middle column even though it is determined anonymously.*

## The solution

#### Small screens

```css
.rowTabled{
  display:table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.header{
  background-color:green;
  display:table-header-group;
}
.footer{
  background-color:green;
  display:table-footer-group;
}
.aside{
  background-color:red;
  display:table-row-group;
}
.colLeft, .colgroup{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="colgroup">
    <div class="colCol left"></div>
    <div class="colCol middle"></div>
    <div class="colCol right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowTabled">
    <div class="colLeft"></div>
    <div class="header">stuff</div>
    <div class="footer">stuff</div>
    <div class="aside">asideeeeeeeeeeeex eeeeee eeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

#### Large screens

```css
main{
  display:table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.colgroup{
  display:table-column-group;
}
.colCol{
  display:table-column;
}
.middle{
  background-color:green;
  width:100px;
}
.left,.right{
  background-color:yellow;
}
.rowTabled{
  display:table-row;
}
.colLeft{
  display:table-cell;
}
.aside{
  background-color:red;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="colgroup">
    <div class="colCol left"></div>
    <div class="colCol middle"></div>
    <div class="colCol right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowTabled">
    <div class="colLeft"></div>
    <div class="header">stuff</div>
    <div class="footer">stuff</div>
    <div class="aside">asideeeeeeeeeeeex eeeeee eeeeeeeee eeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Used flexbox and assigned aside a percentage width. The details are in the CSS portion of Snippet.

- [Flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties)

  - `justify-content: space-between`
  - `order`
  - `flex-shrink`, `flex-grow`, `flex-basis`
- [Relative units of measurement](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/)

  - Viewport width/height `vw` and `vh`
  - Percentage
  - `em`

```css
/* Optional Defaults and Resets */

* {
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font: 400 10px/1 Arial;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}*/

body {
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 160%;
  /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);*/
  line-height: 1;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
/* Demo Styles */

/* All outlines and backgrounds are for presentational purposes */

/* vw/vh viewport width/height 1vw/vh = 1% of viewport width/height */

main {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 35em;
  display: table;
}
/* Flexbox layout will automatically keep .aside to the right with the */

/* property justify-content: space-between; which keeps the max amount */

/* of even space between flex-items (which is .stuff and .aside) */

.colMain {
  /* display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between; */
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 99%;
  min-height: 99%;
  padding: 1em;
  display: table-row;
  width: 700px;
}
/* Removed absolute positioning in favor of flexbox and a percentage */

/* width. .aside will start dis-proportionally expanding while the viewport */

/* expands. The two columns on the right while begin to shrink in response */

/* to.aside's expansion. All this stretching and shrinking happens when the */

/* elements are at 210px or more (210 is 30% of 700px). This behavior is */

/* accomplished by using flex-shrink, flex-grow, and flex-basis */

.aside {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: 0;
  left: 70%;
  /* order: 3; */
  min-width: 30%;
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 100%;
  /* flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 210px;*/
  outline: 2px solid #7c1b38;
  padding: 5px;
}
.aside-on-small-screen {
  background-color: red;
}
.stuff {
  outline: 2px dotted white;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 210px;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /* flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 210px; */
  display: table-cell;
}
#col1 {
  left: 1em;
  top: 1em;
}
#col2 {
  left: 36%;
  top: 1em;
}
/*.stuff:first-of-type {
  order: 1;
}
.stuff:last-of-type {
  order: 2; */

}
/* The HTML shows that the second column (the second .stuff) would be */

/* in-between .aside and the edge of .colMain. Instead of moving it out of */

/* the way in markup (HTML), I used the flexbox property, order. */
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="colMain">
    <div id="col1" class="stuff">stuff</div>

    <div class="aside">aside that must extend all the way to the right until it reaches the window limit</div>

    <div id="col2" class="stuff">stuff</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Flexbox is interesting but it is only supported by recent IE10+ (2012). I want to support IE8+ and is really a pain because something like calc() would be really useful for fix/fluid layout. Sorry for wasting your time, I will edit my question with that specification.

Comment: IE8? I suggest that you design for IE as if the user doesn't run JavaScript then notify the user that he or she is using a relic and to not expect a good UX. You'll be wasting your time expecting IE to play nice. I think I can dumb it down to IE8...

Comment: Please see update, It's semi-responsive, nothing earth shattering, but if you media queries, it'll be ok.

Comment: Let says the two green columns can be merged into one as it was supposed to be, just by adding a cell to the left to maintain the balance, the way the margins between the side columns are behaving is not what was requested. On large screens, the columns are way too far from the center when the absolute positioning was supposed to fix the right one at 20 pixels close of the center column's right side. It's is really... weird, for a layout to see the side columns getting away from the main content...

Comment: In fact, after thinking full days long, I found a solution after reading a lot about advanced display properties. It works really well so I will write it down and if that's not too much to ask after treating your solution of "weird", I would be grateful if you could review it for weaknesses.

Comment: Answer added. Phewww!