# Vertical-align the content of an anonymous cell object

Tags: css, css-tables

I use display table/cell/etc properties but, because of my responsive design, I am stuck with [a rigid HTML structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36271873/3608012), which means I have an [anonymous cell](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes) (the doc is for table element but the concept is the same for `display: table` > it is just here for the explanation). For some reason, the content of my cells are not vertically aligned because on their dynamic content. That's the reason why I need to set their `vertical-align` property to `top`, which can't be set directly for that anonymous cell.

I know you can use display table-column-group/table-column as a workaround to style the width of anonymous cells without breaking my structure. Is there a similar way to vertical-align an anonymous cell object content, knowing that:

- I can't select the anonymous cell, obviously (in the code below, this cell is composed
  of class header and footer).
- I can't set a wrapper, obviously.
- Pure HTML/CSS.
- Compatibility with IE8+.

```css
main{
  display:table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width:100%;
}
.rowTabled{
  display:table-row;
}
.colLeft, .aside{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="rowTabled">
    <div class="colLeft"></div>
    <!-- anonymous cell element-->
        <div class="header">stuff</div>
        <div class="footer">stuff</div>
    <!-- / anonymous cell element-->
    <div class="aside">Aside</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can't say I'm real clear what you mean by "anonymous" cell, even with your link. I believe the objects they're talking about are when you actually use the `<table>` HTML markup. Things like `<tbody>` are automatically inserted by the browser if they're not included in the original markup.

Comment: he mean an "anonymous object" that is inserted around div.header and div.footer as a result of .rowTabled being set display:table-row and .header & .footer not being set display:table-cell... 
still I do not understand what we would like to achieve...

Comment: so can't you just `.rowTabled > div { display: table-cell; }` ?

Comment: daleyjem > Like Giuseppe Grasso said, an anonymous cell is wrapping header & footer div. By doing what you said, you will create four cells instead of three. I commented the HTML to make you understand where is the anonymous cell.  Giuseppe Grasso > I want to vertical-align on top the content of my three cells, I can with the left and the right ones but not the header&footer one because the anonymous cell "wrapper" can't be selected directly.

Comment: @daleyjem: That's why the OP made "anonymous cell" a link in their question...

Comment: Note that the docs *are* for `display: table`, not for HTML table elements. CSS tables are modeled after the HTML table rendering model but are otherwise unrelated to HTML. Based on the code you currently have here it's unclear what sort of vertical alignment you want to apply to the anonymous table-cell with respect to the other cells. You probably know you likely aren't going to get a favorable answer since we're dealing with an anonymous table-cell, but in any case could you be more specific?

Comment: I tweaked the OP but in case I am still not clear: I want the _content_ of all my cells to be vertically aligned on top, which is not the case. Problem: I have an anonymous cell. So: is there a way to vertical align the content of the cells of a display:table without having to select the cells?

Comment: @Some_user: If there's a wrapper for header and footer, the `>` will only select a direct descendant. The `.header` and `.footer` would not receive the `display: table-cell`, just the wrapper itself.